# Create user with Phone number Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am going through Firebase SDK Documentation. I can see codes and example for creating the user with email and password but I cant see any method for creating user with phone  number (JS SDK).
I can see iOS & Android code though.
Am I missing something ?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth?